# Python class is changing global variable without declaring it global

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, global-variables

I made an error while defining a function within a class, yet it doesn't change how the code operates during runtime.

The error I made was using a global variable when I mean to use an instanced variable.

What I meant to write was:

```
self._map_data[screen_pos_layer][y][x] = selected_material
```

Instead, I wrote:

```
map_data[screen_pos_layer][y][x] = selected_material
```

However, the intended functionality (change the color of an LED) doesn't change, no matter if it's the instanced variable or the global variable. The function that actually writes the color into the LED is in a different class.

I thought that could only happen if I include `global <variable>` ? I have very little experience with Python but I'm sure this was true.

```
class Tools(object):

    def __init__(self, _map_data):
        self._map_data = _map_data

    def paint(self, event):
        if selected_tool == select_paint and selected_color != -1:
            for j in range(cursor_size_y):
                for i in range(cursor_size_x):
                    y = screen_pos_y + cursor_pos_y + j
                    x = screen_pos_x + cursor_pos_x + i

                    map_data[screen_pos_layer][y][x] = selected_material
        else:
            return

        moveCursor(event)

tools = Tools(map_data)

# this is a Tkinter object
window.bind_all("<Control-Up>", tools.paint)
```

I tried searching for this but I could only find posts about people wanting to use a global variable in a class, I specifically am trying not to.

Comment: You are simply mistaken. In Python, if a name isn't found in the local scope, it checks globals.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently your code has previously created a global `map_data` variable, so the code you're showing is not re-creating the `map_data` variable, it is only modifying an element of the existing variable.  The existing variable is found via regular name lookup, and so in this case it is found in the global context.

Comment: So a global list's elements can be changed without declaring the list itself as global? That's good to know, thank you.

Comment: Yes, for lists and dictionaries, or any other mutable object.